# Tomcat and Servlet issues

Tags: java, sql, ajax, jsp, tomcat

I'am encountering a problem with my Web Apps and cannot find any answers on the web.

I have a Java Web
   App that works on parallel with
   tomcat and apache using mod_jk.

Everything works fine, but after one
   day of running in tomcat, one of my
   main servlet doing ajax request stop working. All the
   others work fine. By this i mean that i am doing ajax request on other servlet and they work fine.

Wierd thing is that it works for a
   day and then stop the next one (i
   must than reload my WebApps to make
   it work again).

I really don't have any clue or idea
   from where to start investigating
   this problem.

Could you gentle developpers give me a hint or two please ? :)

Comment: start by looking log files  in $CATALINA_HOME/logs/ , anthing of interest there ?

Answer (score 4):

- You may look at your server logs.
- You may use a browser addon like [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) to check the status of your ajax request(any http requests for that matter)
- If you are using a IDE, start the server in debug mode and debug your servlet and troubleshoot from there on.

Comment: Probably apache and tomcat are both producing logs, so check them both.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged SQL as well, I strongly suspect that your webapp is leaking SQL connections. I.e., your webapp is getting a connection and keeping it open all the time and *never* [closing](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) it. Because the connection is been too long open, the DB will force a timeout and close of the connection after a certain period. E.g. MySQL will do that after 8 hours. Reloading the webapp will cause a new connection been acquired and hold. But this doesn't fix the *actual* problem.

This issue is pretty common among new-to-webapp (and new-to-database) developers.

All you need to do is to rewrite your JDBC code so that it properly acquires *and* closes the `Connection` (and `Statement` and `ResultSet`) in the **shortest possible scope**. You also need to use a `finally` block to *ensure* the close for the case an exception is been thrown. Here's a kickoff example:

```
public List<Entity> list() throws SQLException {
    // Declare resources before try.
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Data>();

    try {
        // Acquire resources and query DB in try.
        connection = database.getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement("SELECT id, name, value FROM entity");
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Entity entity = new Entity(); 
            entity.setId(resultSet.getLong("id"));
            entity.setName(resultSet.getString("name"));
            entity.setValue(resultSet.getInteger("value"));
            entities.add(entity);
        }
    } finally {
        // Close resources in reversed order in finally.
        if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
        if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException logOrIgnore) {}
    }

    // Return result.
    return entities;
}
```

If you want to improve connecting performance, then you should consider using a [Connection Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) instead of keeping the connection all the time open.

#### See also:

- [Related SO question: *Servlet stops working after some time*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876901/servlet-stops-working-on-tomcat-server-after-some-hits-or-time/2877496#2877496)
- [Sun JDBC tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html)
- [Sun Exceptions tutorial - The Finally block](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)
- [DAO tutorial (basic code samples how to write/use JDBC properly)](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)